# What's a good solution for a very large scrolling JavaFX pane?

Tags: buffer, javafx-8, smooth-scrolling, custom-scrolling

I'm looking to make an instant messenger, and to give it a fancy, modern-style messaging pane (each message defaulted in a rounded-corner bubble, customizable by the user). However, if a conversation gets long, or if the user scrolls back far in the history, I don't want it to eat up memory.

**Is there an existing (built-in or open-source) JavaFX component that allows for a lot of content to be drawn to a buffer and put on-screen only when needed, but still maintain a traditional scrolling desktop GUI?**

Answer (score 1):

Use a [ListView](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ListView.html).

ListView is a virtualized control which only creates GUI nodes for items that are currently visible, using a [cell factory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ListView.html#cellFactoryProperty) pattern.

Oracle provide a [tutorial for customizing the cells in a ListView](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/list-view.htm).